# Changing the alignment of a colorbox under Large text

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have a colorbox underneath some large text. I would like to move the colorbox slightly left to have the first letter in the colorbox line up with the letter above it.

Here is a picture of what I mean. The top example is what is produced at the moment, the second is photoshooped to show what I want.
[image]

This is the Latex source for my attempt:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{smokyblack}{rgb}{0.06, 0.05, 0.03}
\definecolor{darkjunglegreen}{rgb}{0.1, 0.14, 0.13}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.0in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular*}{7.5in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}

        \textbf{\LARGE \textcolor{smokyblack}{NEO}}  & \Large{theone@gmail.com}\\
        \colorbox{darkjunglegreen!10}{\textbf{\Large \textcolor{darkjunglegreen}{Liberator of Mankind}}} &  555-555-5555 (cell)\\
            & Zion
    \end{tabular*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice, if you present us a minimum working example. But besides this, `\llap` might help you.

Comment: @Jürgen Not sure what you mean, I provided an example in the picture and my attempt..

Comment: @Ryan: Fragments of code are not really useful

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I posted the relevant code,, I had thought minimizing code would be preferred. I can wrap it in a new blank tex document if that is preferred and repost.

Comment: If the upper line begins at the left margin, the colorbox undernreath will overflow into the left margin.

Comment: @Ryan: Yes, edit the post. It's not our job to wrap a document around fragments

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not asking you or anyone to do that. The rest of the document is fluff, and posting the code in the question into a new document class isn't especially helpful. The question is fine as seen by the fact that someone was able to answer my question perfectly..., anyway, wrapped it in a new document and posted..

Comment: but you now appear to have edited the answer into the question which makes the whole post hard to follow in the archives.

Comment: @David, so I did...simple fix is now fixed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the first example, IMO, the problem is with the second one. However, here is a quick trick; use `\colorbox{white}` for the first line.

```
\begin{tabular*}{7.5in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\colorbox{white}{\textbf{\LARGE\textcolor{smokyblack}{NEO}}}  &    \Large{theone@gmail.com}\\
\colorbox{darkjunglegreen!10}{\textbf{\Large \textcolor{darkjunglegreen}{Liberator of Mankind}}} &  555-555-5555 (cell)\\
    & Zion
\end{tabular*}
```

[image]

Comment: why do you say the problem is with the second? I thought it looked better but I know that I could be violating some typesetting or style rules. Anyway, thankyou for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

`\colorbox` puts a margin with a size of `\fboxsep around` the text. So the easiest to compensate this margin is to use a negative `\hspace`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{smokyblack}{rgb}{0.06, 0.05, 0.03}
\definecolor{darkjunglegreen}{rgb}{0.1, 0.14, 0.13}



\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{l}      
        \textbf{\Large L}  \\
        \hspace{-\fboxsep}\colorbox{darkjunglegreen!10}{\textbf{\Large L}}\\
        \colorbox{darkjunglegreen!10}{\textbf{\Large L}}\\
    \end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]